# How do I set length and R2 in the MOSFETs for this wide swing cascode circuit?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

How do I set L and R2 in this MOSFET?

[image]

Conditions:

```
Length:0.19u~40um
Width:0.19u~40um
```

I know fix width with 40um is best, but I don't know how to set R2 and length.

I can simulate the circuit with LTspice.

How can I find the R2 and length parameters?

MOSFETs Q2&Q1 have the same W/L and Q3 and Q4 have the same W/L. When R2 is set to 4k, if the length is set to more than 1u, the accuracy is reduced and the conditions are not met. Therefore, I think I need to change the ratio of Q2&Q1 and Q3&Q4, but I don't know how to approach it.

MOSFET numbering:

```
Q4 Q3
Q2 Q1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you think that setting width to 40um is best but that is not the correct approach. Here is the correct approach

1. You have to decide what VGS-VTH you want to set for the transistors such that you can keep all transistors in proper saturation. Once this is decided, depending on the current flowing in the transistor, your W/L ratio gets set. For now, set L=5um (so as to minimize channel length modulation effects) and adjust W such that you get the desired VGS-VTH for the transistor.
2. Next step is to arrive at the actual W & L of the transistor. For this, we need to know the mirroring accuracy needed for the current mirror. The mirroring accuracy depends on sqrt(W * L). You can then adjust W & L (keeping W/L ratio determined in the above step constant) until you get the desired mirroring accuracy.
3. Resistor R2 determines how much VDS you get for transistor M2. You have to keep VDS > VGS-VTH to keep it in saturation. So, adjust R2 until this constraint is met.

Comment: Actually the mirroring accuracy for a FET in saturation depends on L, and not on W. So 1) choose L for matching; 2) choose W for VGS and VDSAT and speed; 3) choose R2

Comment: So you mean I have to set Length First? If I set Length 5um, I can't satisfied Rout>5M. So It's so hard..

Comment: .param R2=4.05k L=4.8u L2=0.7u-> This setting satisfied Accuracy but Rout is just 1.8M

Comment: What is L2? If Rout constraint is more demanding on length, ofcourse, you can increase it.

Comment: Sry, L2 means M3&M4's length.
And I can't put the values ​​in order. This is because L and R2 affect the accuracy at the same time. But thank you so much for  your advice. I'll try again..